# Issue with regex property equaling {NULL}

Tags: c#, regex, null

I have a regex that I am trying to evaluate the value of in the following method:

```
    private void ValidateText()
    {
        if ((!IsOptional && Text == string.Empty))
        {
            SetIsValid(false);
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.ValidationRegex != null)
            {
                SetIsValid(this.ValidationRegex.IsMatch(this._text));
            }
            else
            {
                SetIsValid(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where:

```
    private Regex ValidationRegex { get; set; }
```

Now, when it gets to `this.ValidationRegex != null` I hover over the `ValidationRegex` value and `{NULL}` is displayed, so I expect my line to return `false` and go into the `else` statement.

Instead, this line returns `true` and I can't understand why. I have attached a screenshot of this below:

[image]

I can't seem to work it out (This is not a threading thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you have in the `Regex` object is `NULL`.

```
var ValidationRegex = new Regex("NULL");
```

This regex is looking for a string `NULL` in the input string (like `This value is NULL.`), and the `ValidationRegex` object is initialized and is *not* null. So, `if` evaluates to `true`.

Just a note: you can't check if a value is NULL using regex.

Comment: Well spotted. This actually turns out to be me translating `NULL` from my sqlite database to `"NULL"` and not `null` like it should. Thanks

Comment: Yes, sqlite is known for that kind of behavior. You need to cast the returned strings to their original types. If you need more help with this, please feel free to drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx), the ToString() of Regex class (which is what Visual Studio is displaying) returns the regular expression pattern that was passed into the Regex constructor.

So I would assume your pattern is NULL.